# Whatsapp: How to hide the status notifications of a person in Whatsapp Desktop?

Tags: desktop, whatsapp, status

I use Whatsapp (Android and Desktop). Although I was able to hide the Status notifications of a certain person in the Android version, I am not able to do this in the Desktop version.
Any tip / help to hide or block these notifications in the Desktop version?

Thank you in advance